# Windows 7, weird/annoying explorer problem

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-management

Whenever you create a new folder, you have to hit the enter key TWICE because first it'll throw an error that "there is no such file..". Okay. Then if you try to delete some, this happens also. Renaming is the same.

[image]

I tried adding a "2" to the end of the folder name, hit enter and got this. Here I can press cancel, nothing happens. If I press retry, the popup disappears and it'll finally change the folder name.

I can't come up with anything for this. Using BitDefender (registered, full protection), Windows 7 Ultimate Retail 32-bit (boxed, English version). The other PC had the same anti-virus protection , but it had Windows 7 64-bit. Both systems are activated, updated totally. I don't remember installing any new stuff on the PCs. All the stuff on the PCs are legal, no cracked / any other software present. It just happened, so to say. Already reinstalled the other PC because I thought * I * messed up something and its just something FUBAR. However, I dont want to reinstall my laptop also.

Any ideas are welcome. (Today I had a strange bug. Windows Explorer had 1.0+gb memory usage with 100% cpu. Killed it, launched a new explorer.exe and thats all. Nothing changed, but it may worth a try. The other PC did NOT have this problem, ever.)

Isn't there a registry fix for this or something?

Comment: I've noticed this on a few occasions but I've not really bothered to do anything about it as it's not a huge worry for me. I'd be interested in a fax though.

Comment: Sadly it was like that at first, only happened occasionally. But now it happens with almost every time when it comes to file-management, which just driving me nuts.

Comment: Try to turn of SearchIndexer service.

Comment: On a related note, on at least two occasions I have unintentionally deleted a folder because I clicked a file or subfolder in the right-hand pane but Explorer was still "active" on the folder in the left-hand pane.  :[  Thank Bill for the recycle bin...

Comment: Vasiliy: Its turned off. I'm using everything utility (as on demand, so its not running always).

Comment: Does it happen with all files/folders, specific items, or does it seem to be random? Do you have any shell extensions installed?

Comment: It happens with all !folders!, (and if I clearly recall sometimes some file are also affected) I want to rename. Can't determine a pattern. | And as far as I know I don't have any shell extension installed. Here is a picture about whats installed : http://noob.hu/2010/05/13/list.jpg (blurred out is an old game, already deleted, 'fake entry')

Comment: Are you running as a standard user, or administrator?  Where are you trying to create/delete these folders?  I'm not familiar with BitDefender (we use Forefront) but this has not ever happened to me on 3 different Windows 7 x64 machines. (home premium, business, ultimate)

Comment: I'm using an Administrator account with UAC off. I try them everywhere, it happens everywhere. :/ (Maybe I should install an Avast or something and do a full scan.)

Comment: Okay malware bytes, avast pro, kasperksy, didnt found anything. ANY IDEA?

Comment: Started bounty, maybe that will call the experts here. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, and I suspect that it might be a Windows hotfix/patch issue, as it appeared right after an update.

Comment: Hmm not a bad thinking. But what to do then? Wait for another fix? oO

Comment: I had a PC that was not used in weeks, and right after I turned it on I did some file-copying before I ran Windows Update. No problems at all... As soon as the update was finished, the same problem emerged even on that PC!

Comment: @Shiki: I'm guessing that you ran Windows Update on the newly installed machine, that would explain why the problem turned up although you did a fresh install.

Comment: The newly installed PC is fine. All the updates are install also. Updates screen: http://noob.hu/2010/05/16/updates.jpg

Comment: I got the same issue: http://superuser.com/questions/145028/win7-could-not-find-item-upon-creation I've tried to check disk, sfc /scannow and safe mode. All result in the same error: http://flx.me/imgdump/flx457.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I see it, either there's either a rogue application in your computer, or Windows has gone bad. The second option may require re-installation.

Your best bet is (in order of desperation):

- See if the problem happens when
  booting in Safe mode.
   If it
  doesn't happen: Then the problem is
  with an installed application or
  driver (most likely video).
   If
  it still happens: Windows is probably
  bad.
- Scan the installed applications and
  uninstall any that look doubtful, Use
  [Revo](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) for that.
- Use [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to verify all
  applications that start with Windows.
- Use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to verify
  that no program is locking the
  directories
- Use [System File Checker](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833) (SFC) to
  scan system files and replace
  incorrect versions of them.
- Refresh Windows 7 by doing an upgrade
  installation.
- Reformat and reinstall Windows.

EDIT

Since we have here two people with the same arcane problem, it might be instructive to find out what you have in common.

Could Shiki add to his question the details for his hardware, Windows version and language, and the list of installed applications? Then TFM could comment on the list.

Here's how one gets a list of all installed applications by using the Windows Instrumentation command-line interface (WMIC) on a text file:

1. Start Command Prompt.
2. Type `wmic` and press Return.
3. You will see a new prompt: wmic:root\cli>
4. Execute
   `/output:c:\appList.txt product get name,version`
   (To terminate use the quit command.)
5. The applications list is found on the file c:\appList.txt.
   It will require some text-editing to reduce the number of lines.

EDIT2

After much research, it seems that Explorer in Windows 7 has many problems with refreshing the files list, which causes problems with all file operations. These problems are well-known but remain unacknowledged by Microsoft. One hopes that they will disappear with the upcoming service pack.

The obvious solution is to use a third-party replacement for Explorer.

Some non-obvious solutions are explored in the extremely long thread found here:
[Windows Explorer doesn't refresh when moving/deleting](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/09fd46ff-65f1-4fa7-ae2d-9f3b2644fad6).
Many people claim having found solutions, which worked for some but not for others.
I list below most of the solutions, in what I consider is the order of likelihood of them working:

1. Remove the computer from the Homegroup
2. Remove all network shares
3. Unchecking MS client for windows, and switching off all the sharing options
4. Delete IconCache.db
5. Sort files in Explorer by name rather than by date
6. Rebuild the Windows Experience Index.

Comment: See if the problem happens when booting in Safe mode. > Will check.  
Scan the installed applications and uninstall any that look doubtful, Use Revo for that > Did that.  
 Use autoruns to verify all applications that start with Windows. > Did that.  
Use Process Explorer to verify that no program is locking the directories > Did.  
Refresh Windows 7 by doing an upgrade installation. > No way, worse than anything.  
  
Use System File Checker (SFC) to scan system files and replace incorrect versions of them. < Very good idea, I was searching for such an app but didnt find anything, thanks!

Comment: Same here, I went through all the steps listed here, no change...

Comment: @TFM: Do you have these problems in Safe mode?

Comment: Okay. Report: SFC said it found some files, fixed them. After a reboot, the problem still there. Safe mode comes with the same problem.

Comment: I still have the problem in safe mode.

Comment: System (it occured on a PC also, but now my laptop is the problem): Lenovo T500. 2gb ddr3, Intel P8600. Windows 7, x86, Ultimate (it happened on x64 , desktop also). Version: retail, up-to-date. Language: english. Posting the list to pastebin....

Comment: Link: http://pastebin.com/5uLm3Er2 (CCC, Lenovo, GlobeTrotter, Nokia: remove these, didnt have them on PC.)

Comment: @Shiki: The only one I can't find is "PX Profile Update". What is it?

Comment: @TFM: How similar is your configuration?

Comment: Here's mine, on a HP 6720s, 3 GB RAM, Windows 7 x64: http://pastebin.com/XWHshxaU

Comment: @Shiki: @TFM: See my last edit.

Comment: Thanks Harrymc I'll try that out tomorrow morning (getting to sleep now, way too late to mess around. I *know* (learnt the lesson) its not good to mess with PCs when you are tired. :))

Comment: @harrymc: Thanks very much for clearing this up! Will read the thread, and get back to you.. Thanks again!

Comment: Okay did all except this "Unchecking MS client for windows, and switching off all the sharing options". How can I do that? (Others didnt help at all.)

Comment: @Shiki: Network -> Network and Sharing Center -> [Local Area] Connection -> Properties -> uncheck client for Microsoft Networks. Also in Network and Sharing Center : Change advanced sharing options.

Comment: If nothing works, then I can't even counsel to reinstall Windows. Although this fixed the problem for some people, others had this problem from the very start. The only sure solution (while waiting for Microsoft to fix the problem) is really not to use Explorer.

Comment: I also conclude that the only point in common that have Shiki and TFM together is that they use Windows 7 with Explorer. Another case of Microsoft shooting themselves bullets in the leg.

Comment: Yeah but there are no usable alternatives so far. (For example if I want to use ALL the Lenovo stuff, I have to stick with Windows.) Uhm Harry one question. Do you know how can I save down my license information? I have some in the house and I managed to mess up the order. Is there a tool for that to save and load it back?

Comment: @Shiki: Almost anything you can do with Explorer you can do with its alternatives. See http://www.simplehelp.net/2006/10/11/10-windows-explorer-alternatives-compared-and-reviewed/. My own favorite is http://www.altap.cz/download.html#salrel.

Comment: @Shiki: For keys, do you mean something like http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/ ?

Comment: Yeah thats it. Will try the alternatives and the key finder. Thanks for everything :)

Comment: Whats the difference between ALTAP and Total commadner? (Altap costs 60$ so yeah ...would like to be sure if it worth it)

Comment: Hmm I used that Ultimate Windows 7 Tweaker or what. Its a free utility and allows to customize Windows 7. What about you TFM?

Comment: Don't spend money on Explorer alternatives. Some free ones are very good.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a small consensus that believes KB980408 maybe the cause of these problem. It may be worth taking a look at these threads:

http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7files/thread/511a2436-99e1-4f5c-9578-60daa08422a1

http://www.overclock.net/windows/721973-msupdate-kb980408-warning-all-win7-x64.html

http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/81527-need-help-unable-rename-move-folders.html

Comment: OMG and I really removed libraries. LOL. Thanks for the link. AWESOME! :) (If this fixes it, I'd give you ALL my points!)

Comment: That .reg file fixed it. Thank you sooo very much.. :)